# What does this function initialization syntax mean?

Tags: go

While looking at the [google plus sign in](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) in go, I found a very interesting pattern.  Here is a trivial example ([live](http://play.golang.org/p/UEH1Mhqp-w)).

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
)

type FuncType func(i int) int

func (fn FuncType) MultiplyByTwo(i int) int{
    return fn(i) * 2
}

func MultiplyByThree(i int) int{
    return i * 3
}


func main(){
    fn := FuncType(MultiplyByThree)
    fmt.Println("returns 2 * 3 * 5: ",fn.MultiplyByTwo(5))
}
```

My question is quite simple, how come can we initiate the FuncType with parentheses?  I do not understant!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Go spec: Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions):

> Conversions are expressions of the form T(x) where T is a type and x is an expression that can be converted to type T.

So,

```
fn := FuncType(MultiplyByThree)
```

`FuncType` is a type. And `MultiplyByThree` is a pointer to function (which is an expression) with the same signature as `FuncType`. Therefore, it can be converted to this type.

BTW, the output is slightly wrong. Should be

> returns 5 * 3 * 2:  30

This is the correct sequence of multiplications. :)